# Extract string between two / from right

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, scripting

Extract string between two / from right

**Command preparation:**

Input:- [Directories name not constant]

**Example 1:-**

```
/dir1/dir2/
```

**Example 2:-**

```
/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/
```

I Want output as below

**Example 1 Output:-**

```
nohup dsmc arch /dir1/dir2/ -subdir=yes > /tsm/backuplogs/dir2_`date +%d%m%y_%H_%M`.log &
```

**Example 2 Output:-**

```
nohup dsmc arch /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/ -subdir=yes > /tsm/backuplogs/dir4_`date +%d%m%y_%H_%M`.log &
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `basename` program to extract the last dir from your paths, like this:

```
path=/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/
echo "nohup dsmc arch $path -subdir=yes > /tsm/backuplogs/$(basename $path)_\`date +%d%m%y_%H_%M\`.log &"
```

The above line will output:

```
nohup dsmc arch /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/ -subdir=yes > /tsm/backuplogs/dir4_`date +%d%m%y_%H_%M`.log &
```

Comment: You should avoid using old and deprecated back-tics, use parentheses like this: `_\$(date +%d%m%y_%H_%M\).log`

Answer (score 4):

Try this to extract substring:

```
basename /dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/
```

Output:

```
dir4
```

---

With bash builtin commands:

```
string="/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/"
string="${string%/*}"           # remove trailing /
echo "${string##*/}"            # remove /dir1/dir2/dir3/
```

Output

```
dir4
```